# Calculate difference between min and max for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I've got table with football odds and I need to calculate difference between the odds where the updated value was MIN and where updated value was MAX for each fixture and for each of the selected markets. In the output I need to get the difference and the odds where the value in updated column was MAX
I would like  to accomplish that with one query.
The table looks like that

```
| fix_id| odds| odds_type | updated| 
|:-----:| ---:| ---------:| ------:|
| 120   | 1.80|   home    |   160  |
| 120   | 1.40|   home    |   150  |
| 120   | 2.00|   home    |   140  |
| 188   | 1.00|   u/o     |   200  |
| 121   | 1.60|   away    |   160  |
| 121   | 1.40|   away    |   150  |
| 121   | 1.10|   away    |   140  |
```

What I'm expecting to get

```
| fix_id| odds| odds_type | updated| diff|  
| -----:| ---:| ---------:| ------:|----:|
| 120   | 1.80|   home    |   160  | -0.2|
| 121   | 1.60|   away    |   160  |  0.5|
```

The code I was trying and it seems to get the difference between the MIN and MAX correct but returns random odds instead off the MAX and I'm not sure if it would be efficient to calculate differences for hundreds of fixtures.

```
SELECT a.*, MAX(a.odds) - MIN(a.odds) difference FROM odds_table a
where odds_type in ('home','away') group by odds_type,fix_id
```

I used to calculate the differences in php and then use them to update different table inside the loop but there is a 1000's of odds so it takes  ages to process.
P.S I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Your query would error out in most of SQL implementations.  MySQL is much more forgiving in this regard.  But it comes with the ability to see randomly selected values.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Last time I tried to help, I got nothing more than a down vote.

Comment: The weird thing is, I thought I answered this exact question already?

Comment: Sorry I didn't look properly on the answer and I thought it was 3 separate queries you suggested to do. I just realize now that was one query sorry I shouldn't even ask this question then. I up voted your original answer and thx for suggestion with the table structure  is much more convenient this way actually

Comment: Well, let's close this one shall we?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If you were using a more recent version of Mysql (which I'd highly recommend) this could be achieved using row_number and CTEs in a much more elegant way however the following should achieve what you are after, and does not rely on MySQLs unique grouping ablities:

```
SELECT o.fix_id,
    o.odds_type,
    SUM(case when max_values.fix_id IS NOT NULL then odds end) AS odds,
    SUM(max_updated) AS updated,
    cast(SUM(case when max_values.fix_id IS NOT NULL then odds end) - SUM(case when min_values.fix_id IS NOT NULL then odds END) AS decimal(10,2)) AS difference
FROM odds_table o 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT fix_id, MAX(updated) AS max_updated
        FROM odds_table
        GROUP BY fix_id
    ) AS max_values ON o.fix_id = max_values.fix_id AND o.updated = max_values.max_updated
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT fix_id, MIN(updated) AS min_updated
        FROM odds_table
        GROUP BY fix_id
    ) AS min_values ON o.fix_id = min_values.fix_id AND o.updated = min_values.min_updated
WHERE odds_type in ('home','away')
GROUP BY o.fix_id
```